# Change application name shown in Windows 10 taskbar

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I make a wpf application and pin its executable file (WpfApp31.exe) to Windows 10's taskbar. Then when I move my mouse onto the taskbar icon of it, it will show a name WpfApp31, like below picture shown.

[image]

What I want to get is to change the taskbar show name to be like a Chinese name "我的应用", while not changing the executable file's name.

How to acheive it?

Thanks!

Comment: See the duplicate, or just set the Window's Title appropriately.

Comment: Set the window's title does not work. It cannot change the popup name of its taskbar pin. @Clemens

Comment: It works, and the reason it doesn't work before is that its old name is not cleared from the registry. Thanks! @Clemens